# Google Search Console doesn't index an alternative language page

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, multilingual

I have this single page site in portuguese.
When this page loads (index.html) it runs a script to verify the browser language and if its not portuguese it forwards the user to an english version of the site (en.html).
At Google Search Console I see that this page (en.html) isn't indexed because it is an alternative language page.
But I want this page to be indexed!
How can I achieve this?
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What is the exact message you see in Google Search Console about this page?  Google generally will index pages in different languages, so I'd like to see their exact wording.

Comment: "Page with redirecting" and "Duplicated page. Google has chosen a different canonic page from the user"